# Getting return codes of URLs python urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I have a list of URLs, some of which do not work now. I want to parse through that list and get the return codes of those URLs and store them in a dataframe.
I have the following code:

```
for url in df['URL'][]:
print(url)
try:
    #print(urllib2.urlopen(url).getcode())
    df['returncode']=urllib2.urlopen(url).getcode()
except:
    df['returncode']='Obsolete'
    #print('obsolete')
```

What I am getting is a column of all 'obsolete's.

```
df['returncode']:
0         Obsolete
1         Obsolete
2         Obsolete
3         Obsolete
4         Obsolete
5         Obsolete
6         Obsolete
7         Obsolete
8         Obsolete
9         Obsolete
10        Obsolete
11        Obsolete
```

Whereas if I print the values I can see the different return codes.

```
http://study.com/odfv.html
obsolete
http://www.meghansfashion.com/uploads/2/1/2/9/21295692/2_75_orig.png
200
http://p16.muscdn.com/img/tos-maliva-p-0068/8ab65f6aac844cdf83526b5662720be3~c5_300x400.jpeg
200
http://config.88-f.net/hb/c1/pxbfwsp
obsolete
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Never use a bare `except:`, because it will turn obvious problems into mysterious problems.   If you're intending to catch exceptions from `urllib2`, consider `except urllib2.HTPPError:`.

Comment: If possible, you should start using Python v3.x - https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: I tried this-

for url in df['URL'][:10]:

    response=requests.get(url)

    df['returncode']=response


But got the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.121.254.141', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /moxa-cgi/getsnapshot.cgi (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x117c62f90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))

Comment: Please edit your question to update it with the new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are entering the result in the DataFrame doesn't work. The command

```
df['returncode']= ...
```

puts the value in *every* row of the DataFrame. So what you're seeing at the end is eleven times the *last* value that was found.

To improve this, you need to put the result into a specific row. You could iterate over the rows, like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    url = row['URL']
    print(url)
    try:
        #print(urllib2.urlopen(url).getcode())
        row['returncode']=urllib2.urlopen(url).getcode()
    except:
        row['returncode']='Obsolete'
        #print('obsolete')
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Getting return codes of URLs python urllib*

---

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to get the http status code on a url, i.e.:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://google.com")
print (response.status_code)
# 200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get http response codes using `urllib2`.  You're most of the
way there, you just need to handle the exceptions properly.  `urllib2`
raises an exception when it receives an error http response.

```
import urllib2

urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://google.com/does-not-exist']

for url in urls:
    try:
        res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        code = res.getcode()
    except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
        code = err.getcode()

    print('{}: {}'.format(url, code))
```

This will output:

```
http://www.google.com: 200
http://google.com/does-not-exist: 404
```

Comment: I get URLerror for some URLs and HTTP error for some. The url errors are getting handles but HTTPerror are giving me BadStatusLine error while looping.

Comment: updated:
For this "http://delivery-us-central-1.openx.net:443" I get bad status line

Comment: You're getting a `BadStatusLine` because you're trying to fetch an `https` url using `http`.  If you spell that url as `https://delivery-us-central-1.openx.net:443/` it will work just fine.  But maybe you also want to catch `httplib.HTTPException` errors and display a suitable error message.